# Can parameters passed from one MVC Controller to another be viewed client-side?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Basic security.

Controller calls another controller, passing a param

```
return RedirectToAction("VerifyEmail", "Account", new { userId = newUser.Id });
```

Another controller receives it

```
public ActionResult VerifyEmail(int userId)
        {
            int test = userId;
            return View();
        }
```

Is the parameter viewable by the client? That is, is it present on the client's machine at any point in time?

Comment: Not unless you pass it into the View that is being returned.

Comment: Depends on your routing. It may be visible in the URL... but other than that, no.

Comment: it also depends on what you are concerned about. I'm not sure if there is any way to hide it completely, but if you only want to remove it from the URL, then put it in a hidden field and use Request.Form in your action to get the UserId again. But if you're asking how to hide it completely from everywhere.. I'm not sure that's even possible..because you still need to pass it to the server somehow..

Answer (score 1):

It technically will be present on the client's machine.   The `RedirectToAction` sends a 302 response indicating a temporary redirection, which the client (browser) will interpret, generally speaking, as a command to issue a new GET request.

If you run fiddler while you'll see something like this coming back across the wire

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /Account/VerifyEmail?userId=12354
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?    
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 04 Mar 2013 17:45:32 GMT
Content-Length: 150
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/Account/VerifyEmail?userId=12354">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Followed by (in my case) as GET request

```
GET /Account/VerifyEmail?userId=12354 HTTP/1.1
```